# Does datacenter connectivity affect server load averages?

Tags: load-average

This may be a stupid question.

My hosting datacenter (InMotion Hosting) just had about an hour of downtime due to 'connectivity issues'.

As soon as everything started coming back up I logged into the sever to check a few things and the server load for the last minute was showing at 13.4. It's dropped in the last 5 minutes so that the load averages currently read at: 5.69, 6.03, 2.84 and are dropping.

Does it make sense that the load averages would skyrocket if there is a connectivity issue or is this symptomatic of a different problem?

Comment: Maybe. All the users affected by the outage might do what they meant to be doing during the outage. If you have short-lived cached data you might see a bunch of cache invalidations. etc.

Comment: It's a dedicated server and most of the sites are fairly low traffic. I'd expect less than a dozen users trying to jump on it.

Comment: Did you run `top` to see what the load was due to?

Comment: it took me a little while to get to top, but it showed the top two functions as httpd and mysqld. I guess it could have been a mysql restart kicking in, but that shouldn't have been needed unless a reboot was needed. Would connectivity issues need a server restart?

Comment: You'd have to ask your host (and the command `uptime` and/or MySQL's logs should tell you if a restart occurred). I suppose kicking out a power plug is *technically* a "connectivity" issue. Shared hosts like InMotion aren't really known for honesty on outages.